# Issue with AJAX to show html rendered by NodeJS in a client javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, crud

Actually i am working in a app based in NodeJS, and i have got a problem for to render a template in request AJAX.

When i execute the following method:

[image]

My server NodeJS, it return me :
[image]

This template is in EJS, but that is not the problem.

I want to show the template return it request AJAX in my current window. But the html doesn't show, the window stays in the same url (login), however, the html is received in the navigator because i can see it with firebug.

I want to do that it to make the request page automatically loads template returned for NodeJS. (panel admin)

In addition, i have to use two heeaders in the request for access control to routes.

fragment "Client.js"

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      autenticarse();
    });

    function autenticarse(){
      $("#credenciales").bind("submit",function() {
        $.ajax({
          // la URL para la petición
          url: $('#credenciales').attr('action'),
          // la información a enviar
          data: $('#credenciales').serialize(),
          // especifica si será una petición POST o GET
          type: $('#credenciales').attr("method"),
          // código a ejecutar si la petición es satisfactoria;
          // la respuesta es pasada como argumento a la función
          success: function (json) {
            if (json.success==true) {
              sessionStorage.setItem("tokenGS", json.token);
              alert("TOKEN: \n"+ json.token);
              redirigir();
            } else {
              document.location.href="http://localhost:8080/loginErroneo";
            }
            // guardo el token en localstorage
            // pido la pagina de 1panel proporcionando mi token
          },
          // código a ejecutar si la petición falla;
          // son pasados como argumentos a la función
          // el objeto de la petición en crudo y código de estatus de la petición
          error: function (xhr, status) {
            document.location.href="http://localhost:8080/404";
          }
        });

        return false;
      });
    }

    function redirect() {
      $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
          request.setRequestHeader("x-access-token", sessionStorage.getItem("tokenGS"));
          request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        },
        // la URL para la petición
        url : '/admin/panel',
        // especifica si será una petición POST o GET
        type : 'GET',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html){

        }
        // código a ejecutar si la petición falla;
        // son pasados como argumentos a la función
        // el objeto de la petición en crudo y código de estatus de la petición
        error : function(xhr, status) {
          document.location.href="http://localhost:8080/404";
        }
      });
    }

  </script>
```

fragment routes.js

```
    // **********************************************************************
    // *                          MIDDLEWARE                                *
    // **********************************************************************
    adminRouter.use(function(req, res, next) {
      // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
      var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.params.token;
      // decode token
      if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, secreto, function(err, decoded) {
          if (err) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Fallo a la hora de verificar el token de autenticacion' });
          } else {
            var payload = jwt.decode(token, secreto);
            // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
            req.user = payload.sub;
            req.decoded = decoded;
            next();
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
      }
    });
    usuariosRouter.use(function(req, res, next) {
      // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
      var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.params.token;
      // decode token
      if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, secreto, function(err, decoded) {
          if (err) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Fallo a la hora de verificar el token de autenticacion' });
          } else {
            var payload = jwt.decode(token, secreto);
            if(payload.exp <= Date.now() ) {
              res.redirect("/401");
            }
            // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
            req.user = payload.sub;
            req.decoded = decoded;
            next();
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
      }
    });
    cardsSortingRouter.use(function(req, res, next) {
      // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
      var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.params.token;
      // decode token
      if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, secreto, function(err, decoded) {
          if (err) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Fallo a la hora de verificar el token de autenticacion' });
          } else {
            var payload = jwt.decode(token, secreto);
            if(payload.exp <= Date.now() ) {
              res.redirect("/401");
            }
            // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
            req.user = payload.sub;
            req.decoded = decoded;
            next();
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
      }
    });
  
    // **********************************************************************
    // *                       RUTAS WEB PANEL ADMIN                        *
    // **********************************************************************
    adminRouter.get("/panel", function(req, res) {
      res.render('1panel');
    });
  
  
  
    adminRouter.get("/audioAyuda", function(req, res) {
      res.render('2audioAyuda');
    });
    adminRouter.get("/estadisticas", function(req, res) {
      res.render('3estadisticas');
    });
    adminRouter.get("/ajustesPerfil", function(req, res) {
      res.render('4ajustesPerfil');
    });
    adminRouter.get("/ayuda", function(req, res) {
      res.render('5ayuda');
    });
    app.use("/admin", adminRouter );
```

I wait that you can help me.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your actual code, not a screenshot.

Comment: In your `success` callback, you have the use the `html` being passed and append it to some element. For example: `$('#targetElm').html(html);`

Comment: @haim770 this guy has your answer. It's a bit of a weird thing your trying to do, but this will do it.

Comment: As a side note, the AJAX request is being initiated as part of a `redirect()` method when in fact you're only redirecting in case of an error. Loading HTML from the server (the `success` case) is by no means a redirection.

Comment: The process is the following:

1) In the login window of the application, a user is identified
2) The client sends a first JS AJAX request to the server, and this responds with JWT.
3) The customer saves his TOKEN JWT sessionStorage
4) Make an AJAX request with your token to the protected url
5) through the middleware server performs the necessary checks
6) sends the customer template
7) The customer being in the login window, it is automatically redigido the administration panel window after authentication.

Comment: @haim770, Can you think of another way to do what I want?

Comment: @AlbertoJimenezdelosGalanes, The flow you describe sounds OK to me. My comment pertained to the term `redirect`, the function is simply loading some page, not redirecting. Perhaps you can name it `loadAdminPage()` or something like that.